# How to type dʒ symbol (IPA) on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I want to type in dʒ on macOS but I don't know how I can type it. I tried ⌥ + keys but it seems that none of the keys is mapped to the symbol. It's not listed [on this page](https://www.webnots.com/option-or-alt-key-shortcuts-to-insert-symbols-in-mac-os-x/).

I use the US Extended keyboard: So how can I type this symbol?

Comment: For general-purpose IPA input, you may be interested in <http://www.i2speak.com/> (no affiliation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ABC (formerly US) Extended, ʒ is made by typing option-shift ; and then z.

In general, to see which key does what, use [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/10.14/mac/10.14).

More info about ABC Extended can be found [here](http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2016/07/os-x-abc-extended-keyboard-layout.html). And [here](http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/).

Comment: Thanks and do you know which key to type in Dvorak? It seems different and has no such symbol with option and shift...

Comment: Or I rather want to know a way to detect which key to type in based on the symbol, if that is possible, since there are still more symbols that I don't know how to type...

Comment: @Blaszard Only ABC Extended can do such things.  You can use Keyboard Viewer to see all the possibilities provided by the Dvorak layout.  If you want to make a custom version of Dvorak which has the special characters you need, a good tool is Ukelele  http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele (temporarily down unfortunately)

Comment: @Blaszard Your second comment seems to indicate you did not read the part about Keyboard Viewer or click on the link there.  Another way to input such characters is via Character Viewer.  https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/10.14/mac/10.14

Comment: ? I read it but sorry if I missed something as it was written in French. But anyway, I meant that I want a way to know which key to type by the input of the symbol, instead of try all the combinations of keys on the viewer.

Comment: For example I'm now looking for a key combination to type in ð but cannot find with option shift semicolon, or other combinations...

Comment: @Blaszard. See. http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/   ETH is at option d

Answer (score 4):

If you know the Unicode name of the character, you can use ⌘ - ^ - Space to bring up a character search. This character is called [Ezh](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0292/index.htm):

[image: screenshot of character selector]

Usually this is used for Emoji, but as you can see, it works for any character.